# How would you structure Alpha Nodes in a Rete Network that has a rule with two conditions found in other rules?

Tags: algorithm, rules, business-rules, rete

Let's say I have three rules:

1. When Object's foo property is 1, output "foo"
2. When Object's bar property is 1, output "bar"
3. When Object's foo property is 1 and bar property is 1, output "both foo and bar"

What would the structure of alpha nodes look like for this scenario? I've seen examples where, given rules 1 and 2, it might look like:

```
      foo == 1 - "foo"
root<
      bar == 1 - "bar"
```

And, given 3:

```
root - foo == 1 - bar == 1 - "both foo and bar"
```

And, given 3 and 1:

```
                  "foo"
root - foo == 1 <
                  bar == 1 - "both foo and bar"
```

Given 3, 2 and 1, would it look something like:

```
       foo == 1 - "foo"
root <           
                  "bar"
       bar == 1 < 
                  foo == 1 - "both foo and bar"
```

or

```
       foo == 1 - "foo"
     /
root-- bar == 1 - "bar"
     \
       foo == 1 - bar == 1 - "both foo and bar"
```

Or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sharing nodes and preserving the order in which properties are tested it would look like this:

```
       bar == 1 - "bar"
root <           
                  "foo"
       foo == 1 < 
                  bar == 1 - "both foo and bar"
```